Property 'groupBy' does not exist on type 'MapConstructor'
I'm trying to use Map.groupBy, but typescript is not happy with this error :
Property 'groupBy' does not exist on type 'MapConstructor'
const inventory = [
            { name: 'asparagus', type: 'vegetables', quantity: 9 },
            { name: 'bananas', type: 'fruit', quantity: 5 },
            { name: 'cherries', type: 'fruit', quantity: 12 },
          ]

        const result = Map.groupBy(inventory, ({ type }) => type)
  

I have typescript 5.4.5 and Node 22.0.0
tsconfig.json targets esnext
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "jsxImportSource": "@emotion/react",
    
    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "types": ["vite-plugin-arraybuffer/types"]
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}


I cannot reproduce your error. It is likely you are not actually using the tsconfig.json file when you compile. How are you compiling?

@jcalz I'm using vite 5.1.6, I have added the full tsconfig.json in my answer

If vite is relevant then you might want to tag it because I have no idea about that. It still seems likely that you're not actually consuming this file when you compile; how, specifically, do you compile it? What command do you run to do so? I suppose it's possible your node_modules has overridden @typescript/lib-esnext, but I'd doubt that. Essentially you're not using the esnext lib that comes with TS5.4.5.

for me update the version of typescript solve it
